# Satchmo USPS IntlRatev2

Tags: python, satchmo, usps

I see in code that Satchmo uses  USPS IntlRate protocol but USPS switched to IntlRatev2.

I was wondering if someone got it working with the new international protocol and if

so what are the necessary changes one needs to add to fully support the latest protocol?

10x